# Jquery toggleClass does not change class

Tags: jquery

I have a problem that I cannot solve with the toggleClass()

When I have this HTML:

```
<div class="select">
  <p>Some Text</p>
  <i class="fas fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

And this jquery:

```
    $('.select').click(function () {
      $(this).find('i').toggleClass('active');
    });
```

Everything works as it should. When clicking on the div with class `select`, the class `active` is added to the `i`

**But** when I have this HTML (with two div):

```
<div class="select">
  <p>Some Text</p>
  <i class="fas fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>

<div class="select">
  <p>Some Text</p>
  <i class="fas fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

And the same jquery as before does not work as it should. If you click on the `first div` the `active class` is not added. If you click on the `second div` the `active class` is added.

How come?

Answer (score 0):

your code seems to be working fine with two divs as well.
let me know if anything else.

```js
$('.select').click(function () {
      $(this).find('i').toggleClass('active');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select">
  <p>Some Text</p>
  <i class="fas fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>

<div class="select">
  <p>Some Text</p>
  <i class="fas fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know what to say, it doesn't work for me...

Comment: thanks to some alerts I have noticed that when there are 2 divs and you press on the first one it is as if that div is pressed twice and therefore the active class is added and immediately removed.